# Return HTTP status code using REST API

Tags: vb.net, rest, httpresponse, http-status-codes

How do we return a HTTP status code with the object returned in REST API using VB.NET Framework 4.0?

I have Googled this and found some solutions like throwing the error before returning the object as below:

```
Public Function InfoAndTerms(ByVal Lang As String) As Information() Implements IService.InfoAndTerms

Dim result() As Information    
Try
    ' Do something and fill result
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New System.Web.HttpException(500, "Error - InfoAndTerms")
Finally  
        InfoAndTerms = result
End Try   

End Function
```

But in my case this function is always returning status 400 instead of 500 and I don't know why.

How do I fix this problem? Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried catching the `HttpException` and interrogating the inner exception?

Comment: isn't there any example? and why they are not catching it in other templates

Comment: Well, I can't say why it isn't causing an exception in other templates (??). However simply put, you're communicating with a server, it knows you're communicating with it, but it can't understand your request, hence the 400 exception. Catching the exception should provide more information on _what_ is causing the problem.

Comment: But if I add catch the status becomes 200

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

According to [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/713442/Error-Handling-in-WCF-RESTful-Service) we just have to use 'WebFaultException' which will change the http status. Now there is also a nice method to return the handled error :

Public Function TestMethod2(ByVal name As String) As String Implements IService.TestMethod2

```
If name = "" Then

    Dim str As New ErrMessage
    str.intErr = 1
    str.strErrMessage = "bla bla bla"

    Throw New WebFaultException(Of ErrMessage)(str, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)

End If

Return name
```

End Function

the returned status here will be 400 (try to change bad request to something else and you will see the difference between returned status num) and personally I prefer to return object Error that I created.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use System.Net

```
Dim statsText As String = httpResponse.StatusCode
MsgBox(statsText)
```